# 'KeyError: (Timestamp('1993-01-29 00:00:00'), 'colName')

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, yahoo-finance

I am trying to create a new column on my stockmarket data frame that was imported form yahoo. I am dealing with just one symbol at the moment.

`symbol['profit']= [[symbol.loc[ei, 'close1']-symbol.loc[ei, 'close']] if symbol[ei, 'shares']==1 else 0 for ei in symbol.index]`

I am expecting to have a new column in the dataframe labeled 'profit', but instead I am getting this as an output:

`KeyError: (Timestamp('1993-01-29 00:00:00), 'shares')`

I imported the csv to a df with 
`parse_dates=True`
`index_col='Date'` setting the 'Date' column as a datetimeindex which has been working. I am not sure how to overcome this roadblock at the moment. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement, you forget the `.loc`

```
symbol['profit']= [symbol.loc[ei, 'close1']-symbol.loc[ei, 'close'] if symbol.loc[ei, 'shares']==1 else 0 for ei in symbol.index]
```

Also in pandas we usually try not use for loop as much as we could .

```
symbol['profit']=np.where(symbol.shares==1,symbol.close1-symbol.close,0)
```

Comment: Many thanks! I am not well versed in coding as I am sure you've discerned, but it works and I am now looking into the np.where() method to better understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be related to the fact that Jan 29th, 1993 was a Saturday

Try shifting the date to the next trading day